# ASP.Net MVC ContentPlaceHolder for MetaKeywords and MetaDescription

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At the moment to set a page title you have this on the Master page

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
```

I also want to have the same principal for MetaKeywords and MetaDescription however I don't think this is correct:

```
<meta name="description" content="<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />" />
```

Can someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Master:**

```
<head runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MetaContent" runat="server" />
    ...
</head>
```

**Views:**

```
<asp:Content ID="MetaContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaContent" runat="server">
    <meta name="description" content="..." />
    ...
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you on StackOverflow 24/7? :)

Comment: Are you employed by StackOverflow? Thought I was on here a lot but I have a full time job as well!

Comment: Btw, eu-ge-ne - you are one of the reasons I started to check out questions tagged not only with "asp.net-mvc". You are answering too much of them. :D